# Pattern replacement for variable declarations in GNU make

Tags: makefile

In GNU make, is it possible to use pattern replacement for variable declarations?  For example, this is a valid target

```
obj/%.o: src/%.c
    gcc -c src/$*.c -o obj/$*.o
```

but this doesn't work

`BUILD_% = gcc -c src/%.c -o obj/%.o`

Comment: Are you trying to create a variable whose name is actually "BUILD_%"? And whose value is actually "gcc -c src/%.c -o obj/%.o"? Or something else?

Comment: Why do you want to *variablize* (or *macrofy*, in Makefile-speak) your `gcc` command?  There may be an easier way than trying to get `make` to evaluate that `%`.

Comment: I was trying to create a way to enable a target to call the string held in BUILD_FOO, defined by BUILD_% = gcc -c src/%.c -o obj/%.o, replacing % with FOO.  It turns out I was going at it the wrong way.  Sometimes when a language doesn't let you do something, it's a sign that it's a bad idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I see three separate questions here.

First: can `%` be used and interpreted in [recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax)?  For instance:

```
gcc -c src/%.c -o obj/%.o
```

The answer is that it cannot: during rule resolution, `%` is evaluated in targets and prerequisites, but not in recipes.  Instead, you have to use `$*`, [which is roughly but not exactly the same thing](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-g_t_0024_002a-956).

Second (if I understand your question correctly): can variables used in defining recipes?  For instance:

```
BUILD = gcc -c src/$*.c -o obj/$*.o

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(BUILD)
```

Yes, they can.

Third (if this is what you mean to ask at all): can rules be parametrized with variables such that the `%` placeholder is taken from a variable in which it acts as an argument?

No, not really.  You can [use a combination of the predefined `$(foreach ...)`, `$(call ...)`, and `$(eval ...)` functions to specify rules parametrized with values taken from variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html), but the values of those variables cannot be supplied by the rule resolution process like the value of `%`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I was attacking the problem from the wrong angle.  In restructuring my targets I found that I didn't need such macrofied variables after all.